# jQuery: Evaluate script in ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json

XML responses from my webapp have both HTML to add to the page AND some have a script to run.

I'm trying to send back XML from my webapp like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
  <html-to-insert>
    <![CDATA[<p>add me to the page</p>]]>
  </html-to-insert>
  <script>
    <![CDATA[ alert('execute me'); ]]>
  </script>
</doc>
```

What I'm doing now is snapping out the `<html-to-insert>` and `<script>` CDATA, inserting the html into the page and eval'ing `<script>`.

I'm looking for criticism on my approach.  Any suggestions from anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd rather send JSON, it's way easier to interpret. Example:

```
// Suppose your response is a string:
// { html: "<p>add me to the page</p>, script:"alert('execute me');" }
var obj = eval( "(" + response + ")" ) ;
eval( obj.script ) ;
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the **jQuery** library to make the XML request to your backend and also parse it

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "your/url/that/returns/xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
      // xml contains the returned xml from the backend

      $("body").append($(xml).find("html-to-insert").eq(0));
      eval($(xml).find("script").text());
    }
  });
});
```

You can find out more about jQuery [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing) and [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax)

I haven't tested it, but it should work according to [this article](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery).

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html) is the best answer that i found. Work perfect:

---

```
element.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
var scriptElements = element.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT');
for (i = 0; i < scriptElements.length; i ++) {
    var scriptElement = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
    scriptElement.type = 'text/javascript';
    if (!scriptElements[i].src) {
        scriptElement.innerHTML = scriptElements[i].innerHTML;
    } else {
        scriptElement.src = scriptElements[i].src;
    }
    document.head.appendChild(scriptElement);
}
```

---

Thanks to [Joseph the Dreamer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575527/joseph-the-dreamer). Original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9014304/2835520).

**EDIT:**

Clarification:

1. scripts only run inside `script` tag
2. added scripts after document load, only take effect if it is added to the `head` tag

Thanks to [Deniz Porsuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2511969/deniz-porsuk) for the comment to improve the answer

Comment: If you appendChild your scripts inside div tags. They will not be executed by browser. Scripts should be appended with "script" tag.

Comment: Which divs are you talking about? I use script tag `var scriptElement = document.createElement('SCRIPT');`. Explain your comment please.

Comment: Yes this is true way. But if you create your script inside div like var divElement = document.createElement('div'); and push innerHTML from scriptElement = document.createElement('SCRIPT');  divElement.innerHTML = scriptElement; script will not be executed by browser.

Comment: I still don't understand why you mention div element if that does not appear in the answer.

Comment: Because I did this mistake, lost hours. And I do not want someone else to lost hours.

Answer (score 0):

JSON would be better suited for this purpose than XML imho.

Answer (score 0):

If you output your ajax request response as `$target.html(response);` scripts will be evaluated by browser with no additional moves from your side.

Comment: Good answer if you're using jQuery as this simplifies your code, although for me personally I'm trying to remove jQuery from my code, and `.innerHTML` doesn't eval the scripts, while jQuery's `.html()` method does, so I need to eval it manually and I can't find the source jQuery code for `.html()` in their repo.