# Javascript slider not working when using AJAX to open up the page

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools, slider

I am trying to open a HTML page using ajax on click of a button.

And the HTML page that I am opening has a javascript slider in it, which works fine it I open up the page by itself, but the slider stops working if I open it using my index.html via ajax.

I am putting my the code for both pages for you to see:

The index.html (which is using the ajax to open "SayHello.html") code is below:

```
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        //Gets the browser specific XmlHttpRequest Object
        function getXmlHttpRequestObject() {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                return new XMLHttpRequest(); //Not IE
            } else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
                return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //IE
            } else {
                //Display your error message here. 
                alert("Your browser doesn't support the XmlHttpRequest object.  Better upgrade.");
            }
        }           
        //Get our browser specific XmlHttpRequest object.
        var receiveReq = getXmlHttpRequestObject();     
        //Initiate the asyncronous request.
        function sayHello(x) {

            //If our XmlHttpRequest object is not in the middle of a request, start the new asyncronous call.
            if (receiveReq.readyState == 4 || receiveReq.readyState == 0) {
                //Setup the connection as a GET call to SayHello.html.
                //True explicity sets the request to asyncronous (default).
                if(x==3)
                    receiveReq.open("GET", 'SayHello.html', true);
                else if(x==4)
                    receiveReq.open("GET", 'SayHello2.html', true);             
                //Set the function that will be called when the XmlHttpRequest objects state changes.
                receiveReq.onreadystatechange = handleSayHello; 
                //Make the actual request.
                receiveReq.send(null);
            }           
        }
        //Called every time our XmlHttpRequest objects state changes.
        function handleSayHello() {
            //Check to see if the XmlHttpRequests state is finished.
            if (receiveReq.readyState == 4) {
                //Set the contents of our span element to the result of the asyncronous call.
                document.getElementById('span_result').innerHTML = receiveReq.responseText;
            }
        }
    </script>
<table class="nav">
      <tr><th>sd</th></tr>
      <tr><td><a href="javascript:sayHello(3);">Say Hello</a></td></tr>
      <tr><td><a href="javascript:sayHello(4);">Turvey, Kevin</a></</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Mbogo, Arnold</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Shakespeare, Bill</td></tr>     
    </table>
    <br /><br />

    <span id="span_result"></span>
```

And the SayHello.html code is below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<!-- Mirrored from woorktuts.110mb.com/art_of_reuse_code/index4.html by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2010], Tue, 14 Feb 2012 15:07:17 GMT -->
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Horizontal Carousel</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools.svn.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEvent('domready', function(){ 
      var totIncrement      = 0;
      var increment         = 212;
      var maxRightIncrement = increment*(-6);
      var fx = new Fx.Style('slider-list', 'margin-left', {
                duration: 1000,
                transition: Fx.Transitions.Back.easeInOut,
                wait: true
       });

       //-------------------------------------
      // EVENTS for the button "previous"
      $('previous').addEvents({ 
          'click' : function(event){ 
          if(totIncrement<0){
                    totIncrement = totIncrement+increment;
                    fx.stop()
                    fx.start(totIncrement);
                }
            }                 
      }); 

       //-------------------------------------
      // EVENTS for the button "next"
      $('next').addEvents({ 
          'click' : function(event){ 
             if(totIncrement>maxRightIncrement){
                 totIncrement = totIncrement-increment;
                fx.stop()
                fx.start(totIncrement);
            }
          }               
      })


});
    </script>


<style type="text/css">
    body{
        font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px; color:#333333;
        background-color:#FFFFFF;
    }
    a:link, a:visited, a:hover{color:#0066CC; text-decoration:none;}
    #slider-stage{width:632px; overflow:auto; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden; height:200px; margin:0 auto;}
    #slider-buttons{width:632px; margin:0 auto;}
    #slider-list{width:2000px; border:0; margin:0; padding:0; left:400px;}
    #slider-list li{
        list-style:none; 
        margin:0; 
        padding:0; 
        border:0; 
        margin-right:4px;
        padding:4px; 
        background:#DEDEDE;
        float:left;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h3>More tutorial here: <a href="http://woork.blogspot.com/">http://woork.blogspot.com</a></h3>
<p>Click on Previous or Next Button </p>
<div id="slider-stage">
<ul id="slider-list">
    <li id="l1">Box 1</li>
    <li id="l2">Box 2</li>
    <li id="l3">Box 3</li>
    <li id="l4">Box 4</li>
    <li id="l5">Box 5</li>
    <li id="l6">Box 6</li>
    <li id="l7">Box 7</li>
    <li id="l8">Box 8</li>
    <li id="l9">Box 9</li>
    <li id="l10">Box 10</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="slider-buttons">
<a href="#" id="previous">Previous</a> | <a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
</div>
</body>

<!-- Mirrored from woorktuts.110mb.com/art_of_reuse_code/index4.html by HTTrack Website Copier/3.x [XR&CO'2010], Tue, 14 Feb 2012 15:07:20 GMT -->
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "ht$
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga$
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-1497692-16");
pageTracker._trackPageview();
} catch(err) {}</script>
```

Please help.

Regards
Zeeshan

Comment: Check this, it might help too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158075/jquery-evaluate-script-in-ajax-response You'll need to call eval() on the response script tag.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript loaded through AJAX doesn't execute. You need to move the code that binds all events to the the `handleSayHello` function. That goes for your `domready` event, and the `previous` and `next` click events.

Comment: actually, mootools can import scripts via `evalSCripts` or `evalResponse` options that you pass on to the request class. though it won't launch a domready event, no.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your slideshow code to be inside a function like:

```
function startSlideshow() {
    // code for slideshow without domready event here
}
```

Call it inside domready(if needed) and call it on each time you load the content.

```
//...
document.getElementById('span_result').innerHTML = receiveReq.responseText;
startSlideshow();
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, since you are loading `"SayHello.html"` with ajax the javascript code you have in there does not get executed.

So keep the `"SayHello.html"` with only html, and after you change the .innerHTML in `" index.html"` call a function to do whatever you like that should be located also in `"index.html"`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it with the `.ajaxComplete()` method. So:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    //do something

});
```