# How to call a function from code returned from an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, function

Example function:

```
function myFunction() {
  alert("Test");
}

myFunction();
```

This will run fine when called in a normal HTML webpage. But if this is part of the innerHTML content that is returned from an AJAX call, the function call `myFunction();` won't work.

For example, if the content of a div `TestDiv` is changed via AJAX, and the innerHTML contains the following:

```
<span>AJAX Result</span>
<script language="JavaScript">myFunction();</script>
```

This code will not work when the AJAX request is complete. How can this be fixed?

Comment: We can't help if you don't show how you're handling the AJAX response

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Evaluate script in ajax response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158075/jquery-evaluate-script-in-ajax-response)

Comment: Scripts don't get run when you insert them with `.innerHTML`. You have to create a script node explicitly. If you use jQuery's `.load()` method, it will take care of this for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your function in the success method on the ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'your url',
   data: { data: data},
   success: function(data) {
      // Your function
      myFunction();
   }
});
```

btw if you're using html5, the type is no longer needed on the script tag

```
<script></script>
```

otherwise it's

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: The AJAX request will be returning HTML output, as well. Is it possible to return both "innerHTML" content and the argument "data"?

Comment: the innerHTML will be data, you can just parse is and append to to a div or manipulate it.